# Python MySQLdb Error 1062 exception not working

Tags: python, mysql, duplicates

I am trying to update datasets in my MySQL database with a Python 2.7 script. I am updating a field, that has the unique option enabled. When I try to add a duplicate entry, Python does not give me an error message.

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect(
 host=DB_HOST,
 db=DB_DB,
 user='root', passwd='',
 charset="utf8"
)

cur = connection.cursor()

sql = "UPDATE type SET article_code='Duplicate_Code' where id=9"
try:
    cur.execute(sql)
    connection.commit()
    print "No ERROR"
except:
    print "ERROR"

connection.close()
```

OUTPUT: No ERROR

The dataset, however, is not updated. If I enter the same SQL Code in the phpMyAdmin interface, I get the following message:

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry 'Duplicate_Code' for key 'article_code'
```

I would like my Python script to go into the except option. 
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you read through examples here: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#mysqldb

it states that you should use something more akin to this:

```
cur.execute("""UPDATE type SET article_code=%s where id=%s""", ('Duplicate_Code', 9))
```

as the `9` in your query will get converted to `'9'` which probably does not exist as a key hence your query does nothing, meaning always success.

Also as a side note it's advisable to always use this pattern as this way MySQLdb will escape your values whereas otherwise you/others may be tempted to do something that will open you up to SQL injections.

Edited out `'Duplicate_Code'` from query body